# How to group only particular row of table

Tags: sql

I have a table with `UserId`, `UserName` column like:

```
UserName    UserId
sakthi      50
sakthi      50
sakthi      50
sakthi      50
ganesh      40
ganesh      40
ganesh      40
```

I want to group where count(userId)>3

I want group record like:

```
UserName    UserId
sakthi      50
ganesh      40
ganesh      40
ganesh      40
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the grouping?  Do you want the max `UserId`? In your example why is `sakthi` grouped but `ganesh` not?

Comment: the count of entries for sakthi = 4 ganesh 3.  3 is not > 3 so it doesn't group.  interesting question think it will involve a union to do though.  What flavor of SQL?  I'm thinking of using a CTE but dont' know if it will be supported (MySQL, SQL Server, oracle (and what version?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to break your `SELECT` statement into two parts and `UNION ALL` them together.

Something like this (obviously change for your data):

```
SELECT UserName, UserId
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY UserName, UserId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
UNION ALL
SELECT UserName, UserId
FROM Tbl
WHERE UserId NOT IN
(
    SELECT UserId
    FROM Tbl
    GROUP BY UserName, UserId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
)
```

[Example SQLFiddle...](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f71f73/3)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you may find more readable ways, depending on your dbms (cte in sql server, for example). You could also create a view with the "more then 3 duplicates").

But one way to go could be to use an UNION ALL (an UNION would remove duplicates)

```
select
 UserName, UserId
 from table
 group by UserName, UserId
 having count(*) > 3

union all

select t.UserName, t.UserId
from table t
where not exists (select null
                  from table t1
                  where t1.UserName = t.UserName and t1.UserId = t.UserId
                  group by t1.UserName, t1.UserId
                  having count(*) > 3)
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbc5e/2)